# How to stop a script if not using function or while loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So basically want to stop a script if an if statement is not met, the statement is this:abbrevationabbrevation

```
if x > 40 : print ("Please enter a number between 2 and 40")
```

If the user enters `41` for example, I don't want the program to continue running, but at the moment it does.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Did you know if you copy/paste your post title verbatim into Google, you will have your answer?

Comment: Been looking for the last day before asking on here, can't find an answer. :)

Comment: not using a function or while loop? then only option to exit from script would be `sys.exit()`

Comment: Tried that, problem is the rest of the script won't work if I do that, so if they enter a completely valid number like 20, it still won't work cause program told it to exit before it got to that point.

Comment: @LM `sys.exit()` should always be inside a condition otherwise rest of the code would automatically become unreachable

Comment: @LM The consequences of an `if` should be on the next line. It executes all the indented lines after it.

Comment: This is beginning Python syntax.

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys

if (x > 40):
    print ("Invalid input received. Exiting now")
    sys.exit()
else:
    # do the result of your program
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution could be to raise an exception that will ultimately stop your script from running

```
if x > 40 or x < 2:
    raise Exception("Please enter a number between 2 and 40")
```

you can call `sys.exit()` which will raise `SystemExit` exception or raise the same exception to play safe

Answer (score 0):

As mad_ mentioned, you can just use [exit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#exit) from the sys module

```
import sys
if x > 40:
    sys.exit()
else:
    print('do something')
```

Comment: This is backwards from what he wants.

Comment: My bad, I went straight to the point of the functionality on the title and not the actual requirement but hopefully the idea helps, and just fixed it

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `break` statement. Simply put `break` in the if condition or the while loop

Comment: I think the "if not using function or while loop" in the title is because they already know about control flow tools like `return` and `break`